# PHP selected item

Tags: php, select, post

i got this script below. How do i get the answer from the selected item?

how can i get the option back with the $_POST?

```
<?php
mysql_select_db("internetsites");
$query1 = "SELECT * FROM internetsites ORDER BY name_site";
$result = mysql_query($query1) or die(mysql_error());
?>
        <form name="delete" action="delete.php" method="post">
    choose a site you want to delete.
    <select>
    <?php
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
  echo "<option value=" . $row['name_site'] . "'>" . $row['name_site'] . "</option>";
 }
?>
</select>
<input type="submit" value="delete">
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: mysql_query is deprecated and you should look into using ADOdb or PDO

Answer (score 2):

You give your select a name atribute, then you take the whole code inside `<form  method="post" action="delete.php"></form>` and then you use $_POST['nameattribute'].

Answer (score 1):

Try this, To Post form elements need input `name` attribute,

```
    <form name="delete" action="delete.php" method="post">
            choose a site you want to delete.
            <select name="name_site" id="name_site">
            <?php
                while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
                {
                    echo "<option value='".$row['name_site']."'>" . $row['name_site'] . "</option>";
                }           
           ?>
        </select>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="delete">
    </form>
```

in delete.php,

```
<?php 

    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
       echo $_POST['name_site'];
   }
 ?>
```